# backgroundPositionX not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, animation, background-position

I have play with youtube's sprite animation but there is a problem. `backgroundPositionX` won't work under Firefox (but works on Chrome and IE8)...
This is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/74RZb/

Extra info: the problem is that under firefox It doesn't change the background position (won't play the animation)... there are no errors, just doesn't change the background position.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support backgroundPositionX, but it does support [background position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position)

So we can do something like this:

```
psy.style.backgroundPosition = x+'px 0';
```

This sets the background position, X first, then Y.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/74RZb/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I will click the "accepted answer" button once stackoverflow alows me :)

Comment: Its right, but look at my answer its working fine from your answer. Your code is working slowly.

Comment: @Andy Yeah you are right. I also vote up your answer. Chill.. I tried your formula, but Its working slowly. So I changed it 60 to 30. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

This works in IE, FF and chrome:

background-position: 0 center;

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. `NX` is number of pixels in axis X and `NY` in axis Y.

```
background-position: calc(NXpx) NYpx;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using like this:

```
background-position: calc(100% - 20px) center; // working on chrome and ff
background-position-x: calc(100% - 20px); // working on ie
```

Comment: When answering questions please provide explanation so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Background position-x can work in firefox you just have to specify a fixed background-y position.  Here is a function I wrote to move a ribbon from left to right.  At first it did not work when there was just a position-x specification, well it worked in IE but not FF.  This was my solution.  It is the actual code with comments from my site that works in both IE and FF:

```
   //starts ribbon motion at bottom of animation div 
    function startMotion() {
        var ribbonMove = setInterval(function () { ribbonMotion() }, 50);
        var x = 0;
        var cycles = 0;

        function ribbonMotion() {
            //background position moves on the x plane and is fixed at 0 on the y plane (single plane specification does not work in FF)
            document.getElementById("ribbon").style.backgroundPosition = x + "px" + " " + 0 + "px";
            x++;
            if (x == 800 || x==1600 || x==2400 ||x==3200) {
                cycles++;

              //sets number of cycles before motion stops (max 4 cycles)  
            }
            if (cycles == 3) {
                clearInterval(ribbonMove);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work even if you set background-position-y in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

First install jquery migration

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Include these on your html

The $.browser property allows you to target browsers you want to apply your style into

In this case for background-position can be changed to property supported backgroundPosition

Available flags are - webkit
- safari - opera - msie (for IE) - mozilla

Example for IE or Firefox

```
if ( $.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
        $(".element").css('backgroundPosition', position + "px 0");                
}
```

for chrome

```
if ( $.browser.webkit) {
        $(".element").css('backgroundPosition', position + "px 0");                
}
```

I got mine working and for all IE

Cheers