# JQuery Animate Background position Cross browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

it seems am not able to get this to work:

```
$("#animation").animate({backgroundPosition:"-100px 10px"});
```

I tried this it works, But not on FFox:

```
$('#animation').animate({
  'background-position-x': '10%',
  'background-position-y': '20%'
}, 10000, 'linear');
```

div:

```
<div id="animation" style="border: 0px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); margin: auto; width:550%;height: 100%;background-size:100% 100%; overflow:hidden; padding: 0px; background-image: url(images/pano.png); background-attachment: scroll; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 40px inset; background-position: 180px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;display: none;"></div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sorfect/34psJ/1/
I'm using JQuery 1.8.
Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't think it likes the percentage. Try changing it to px just to see if something happens.

Comment: I did, still doesn't work with firefox.

Comment: Does it work correctly in chrome? Do you have a live demo available? Or maybe a codepen/jsfiddle? *Edit:* See this: http://codepen.io/vobpler/pen/KyHnf

Comment: JsFeddle is now in the edit.

Comment: @qwerty your codepen works on Chrome but not on FF, also mine, what I want is to get it work on at least Chrome and FF.

Comment: If all you want to do is run the animation of the horse galloping, why are you trying to change the value of `background-position-y`?

Comment: Actually not, this is only an example I made now for the working and not working code, I will use the same way to work with something else. and in all cases I don't need the `background-position-y`

Comment: If you don't really care about ie9- and want good (better) performance than Javascript (as well as cleaner code) i strongly suggest using CSS3 animations. Maybe a IE polyfill for that if you need support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so if you just want to animate the `x` position, you're lucky as animating `y` for `background-position` does not work in jQuery. So for `x` use:

```
'background-position': '10%'
```

but if you want to increment the position in order to animate a series of frames, you need to increment thus:

```
'background-position': '+=10%'
```

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raad/34psJ/3/) for a working example with stop/go controls.

Comment: There is a disadvantage for '+=10%'. It resets also 'background-position-y'.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this would help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948617/backgroundpositionx-not-working-on-firefox) for why it is not working in Firefox. I was working around with your code. Following code block is behaving in the same way of your code.

This behaving same way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#animation').animate({'background-position': '10%'}, 10000, 'linear');
});
```

To

```
$('#animation').animate({
 'background-position-x': '10%',
  'background-position-y': '20%'
}, 10000, 'linear');
```

And this code block is working in Firefox too.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#animation').animate({'background-position': '10%'}, 10000, 'linear');
 });
```

For further reference just check the above given links. Those will help you.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code to animate background position along both x and y direction and it is less cpu expensive

```
var x=0;
window.setInterval(function(){
$('#animation').css('background-position',x+'px '+x+'px');
x=(x-4)%1100;//1100 is width of background image in px
},70);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try Keith Wood's [jQuery Background Position Animation plugin](http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html)? I ended up using it some years ago when I came to a project late and needed a solution for background animating and didn't have the time to investigate why my code was failing cross browser (quick and dirty - hey, there was a deadline looming large!) and I'll be honest it's one of the few plugins I keep on coming back to.

There are examples on the linked page, so I won't bother repeating them, but hats off to Mr Wood as his plugin has never failed me.