# image sliding not working in FF

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I am trying code as mentioned in below link.

http://codepen.io/relfor/pen/qKjpL

This is working in Chrome. But not in FF. Any idea why this is happening?

Note : I am trying in MAC FF.

FF that I have is the latest version. 23.0.1

[image]

---

**To get it working with all browswer, I did below**

### css

```
#offerId1 {
    background-position-x:-65px;
    background-position:-65px;
}
```

javascript

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#offerId1').animate(
    {'background-position-x':'300px', 'background-position':'300px'},
    2000,
    function(){
        $('#offerId1').css('background-position-x','-65px');
        $('#offerId1').css('background-position','-65px');
    })}, 1800)
```

Comment: what version of ff are you testing this on?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht : updated question... please see info there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly it's your css not working try this I have try this hope this work [backgroundPositionX not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948617/backgroundpositionx-not-working-on-firefox)

Try this at js part and you will see it's working

```
setInterval(function(){
$('button').animate(
  {'background-position-x':'300px'},
  2000,
  function(){
    $('button').css('background-position-x','-65px').css('color','black')

  })}, 1800)
```

That was just a guideline. This is working see http://codepen.io/arifmahmudrana/pen/Eoefn

Comment: nope.. its not working... you can check in the link i provided

Comment: @FahimParkar I have updated my answer go to http://codepen.io/arifmahmudrana/pen/Eoefn it is working