# Animate background position different behaviours

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm not that good with jQuery animations, but i'm trying to animate an background image when mouse enters on its element. The animation is simple, mouse enters, the image moves a little to the left. Mouse leaves, image returns to its position.

I could have that working on Chrome, but with a different behaviour in IE. FF doesn't event move anything. My is the following:

```
$(".arrow").on("mouseenter", function()
{
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ "background-position-x": "75%" });
}).on("mouseleave", function()
{
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ "background-position-x": "50%" });
});
```

Where `.arrow` is a div with these properties:

```
.arrow {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Right-facing-Arrow-icon.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 16px
}
```

[And here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q94Sm/).

What is most strange for me is the case of IE. It seems that the animation start always from left to right, not middle right. It occours when mouses leaves too. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Firefox doesn't support backgroundPositionX, but it does support [background position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position)

Try this code in **firefox** and **InternetExplorer**:

```
$(".arrow").on("mouseenter", function()
{
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ "background-position": "75%" });
}).on("mouseleave", function()
{
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ "background-position": "50%" });
});
```

More Info: [backgroundPositionX not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948617/backgroundpositionx-not-working-on-firefox)

Here is <kbd>[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnLa4/1/)</kbd> working well with FF and IE

Comment: Nice, this fixed both FF and IE problems, as well keep Chrome working too. [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q94Sm/2/). Thank you.

Comment: Great @DontVoteMeDown you can accept answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I know Manwal has solved it , but it can also be done very easily in CSS3 like so:

```
    .arrow {
        float:left;
        width: 50px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Right-facing-Arrow-icon.jpg) no-repeat center;
        background-size: 16px;
        transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    }

        .arrow:hover {

            transform :translateX(50px);
        }
```

where translate 50px will be the value you wish to move it along the X axis

Comment: Nice tip. How much *cross-browser* it is ?

Comment: That may be the catch, heres W3schools chart: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Comment: I prefer anything but w3schools, like [this](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions). I will take a look, besides, I will keep the accepted answer beucause it answers the question. I have upvote your answer. Thank you dude.

Comment: thanks for link, i may have a new favorite reference site :), thanks