# How to change CSS background-position for the X axis only?

Tags: css, css-animations, background-position

I'd like to animate the background-position of some div with css like this:

```
@keyframes wave{
    from{
        background-position: 80% center;
    }
    to{
        background-position: 160% center;
    }
}
```

This is a very simple animation, but what happens if the background-position in the y axis should change dinamicly? I know of `background-position-x` and y but...

**Is there real support for the `background-position-x` and y rules? Or are they just phantoms today?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`background-position-x`](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Apr/0188.html):

```
@keyframes wave{
    from{
        background-position-x: 80%;
    }to{
        background-position-x: 160%;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the support for this? Because it is not working on my example

Comment: [Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-position) and [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/j1n68o7k/)

Comment: That can't be the support as it is not working on firefox (though it is in chrome)

Comment: Looks like [Firefox doesn't fully support level 4 standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948617/backgroundpositionx-not-working-on-firefox), sorry about that. maybe you should consider using JS.